# Charging an object by induction

Tags: electrostatics

when charging a sphere by induction using a (-) charged object , and we put it to the right side of the sphere, electrons are pushed to the left side , so we ground the left side and the excess electrons escape. but what if we grounded the right side ( which has less electrons than usual ) wouldn't electrons flow from the ground  to neutralise this side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you keep the (-) charged object near the sphere, the electrons that'll flow from ground to neutralise the right side will also get pushed towards the left side, though the proportion might vary.

That's what I thought. But here's another logic. If the (-) charged object can push incoming electrons from the ground to the left side of the sphere, it can also push them down to the ground i.e. it will never let the ground donate electrons to the sphere via right side due to electrostatic repulsion.

**Answer:** No, nothing will happen if you try to ground the right side. No neutralization, no -ve charging.

I suggest you try this out. It would be a fun experiment.

Comment: so eventualy no longer electrons can be pushed because of the repulsion from the (-) left side then if we remove the ground and the charged object the object will be negatively charged , that what i figure out , but is it possible to induce a (-) charge using a -ve charged object?

Comment: @martin Made an update!

Answer (score 0):

The way I see this problem is that electrons will move due to a difference in potential between the sphere and the ground.  Now the ground is taken to have a potential of zero.  However, with our sphere, it's harder to determine what the potential is going to be

I came across this topic [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/230440/charging-by-induction) where the answerer pointed out that all points on the sphere will have the same potential.  I believe the proof is that we are dealing with an **equilibrium state**, so there cannot be a potential difference between different points on the sphere.  (If the potential difference does exist, that means electrons will start to move within the sphere and that would not be an equilibrium state any more).

So now my line of reasoning is this:

1. The electron flow to/from the ground is due to the potential difference between the sphere and the ground.
2. All points on the sphere have the same potential
3. Therefore, *it does not matter where you put the grounding wire*.
   Using your example of placing a negative (-) object on the right side of the sphere, grounding the right side of the sphere would still result in electrons flowing down to the ground.  With reference to **Cheeku's** answer above, you could probably see it as the negatively charged object pushing even more electrons down the grounding wire and into the ground