# Charging by induction

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, potential-energy, superconductivity, voltage

When we charge an conductor by induction and grounding, we first bring a negative charge to the conductor. As a result the mobile electrons of the conductor get repelled and stay far from the negative charge. After we ground that conductor and then those repelled electrons go to the earth.

- But why? There doesn't seem to be any potential difference.
- So why do those electrons leave the conductor without any reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case there will be a negative potential on the
conductor and the potential on earth
is zero. When you ground it there will
be a potential difference, so the
electrons will move until the
potential difference becomes zero ,i.e. electron will move to ground.
Then finally the potential on the
conductor will also be zero.

Since, a neutral metal ball have no potential of its own , it will have -ve potential due to external -ve charge.

[image]
The positive charge induced on one side of sphere will cancel negative charge on other side. Configuration of charges is such that no charge is induced at centre of sphere.

Now potential at centre will only be due to outer negative charge and potential due to two sides of sphere cancel each other exactly.

Potential at centre = potential at any point on sphere
= $-kq/r$

where $r$ is distance from center of sphere w.r.t. RHS.

Edit : Another case:  If inducing charge is not far.

Consider your -ve charge at distance of $r$ from centre of sphere of radius $R$.

Now, Potential at point near to sphere will be
$\frac{-kq}{r-R}$

Potential at far point will be
$-kq/(r+R)$

Due to $PD =\frac{kq(2R)}{r^2 - R^2}$
electron move from near side$N$ to far side $F$.

N has positive charge although -ve potential
and F has -ve charge .

Now, potential at far side had become more -ve and at near side less -ve.

As +ve charge is induced at $N$ ,
consider a charge $+q'$ at distance $\frac{r}{R}$ from $N$ which had induced this +ve charge.

Note: there is no such charge q' in real, just let it.

Since net charge on sphere is 0.
An equal $-q'$ charge at distance $R/r$ from F will also be formed which had induced -ve charge at F.

Now, due to PD electrons in sphere move,so that, potential at $F$ and $N$ are same.

$$V_{N} = \frac{-kq}{r-R} + \dfrac{kq'}{\frac{R}{r}}+\dfrac{-kq'}{2R-\frac{R}{r}}$$

$$V_{F}=\frac{-kq}{r+R}+\dfrac{-kq'}{\frac{R}{r}}+ \frac{kq'}{2R - \frac{R}{r}}$$

When potential at point N and F will be equal
$k\frac{-q}{r-R} + k\dfrac{q'}{\frac{R}{r}} + \frac{-kq'}{2R - \frac{R}{r}} = \frac{-kq}{r+R} + \dfrac{-kq'}{\frac{R}{r}} + \dfrac{kq'}{2R - \frac{R}{r}}$

On solving ,
$q' = -\frac{qR^2(2r-1)}{2r(r^2- R^2)(1-r)}$

So, potential at N $V_{N}= \frac{-kq}{r-R} + -\frac{kqR^2(2r-1)r}{2r(r^2- R^2)(1-r)R} -\frac{kqrR^2(2r-1)}{2r(r^2- R^2)(1-r)R(2r-1)}$

On solving $V_{N} = -k\frac{qr}{r^2-R^2}$
Which is potential at any point on sphere.

When $r>>R$

$V = \frac{-kq}{r}$

Comment: ok but how we'll say that mathematically that there is a negative potential on that conductor due to the external charge.

Comment: ok sir tell why u r saying outer POSITIVE CHARGE and how value of Vn is equal to V of any point of the sphere.

Comment: If Vn is different, charge will flow in conductor and make voltage equal again. Here while inducing charge I considered that flow of charge due to unequal potentials.

Comment: There would be no net potential due to sphere by itself. Potential of metalic sphere can only be due to electric field of outer positive charge.

Comment: but here inducing charge or outer charge is not positive sir.

Comment: Charge is positive wrt LHS

Comment: How -Kq/(r-
R)+Kq'/(r/R)= -Kq(r-R) - Kq'(r/
R) ?????   Its wrong.     $$-Kq/(r-
R)+Kq'/(r/R)= -Kq(r+R) - Kq'(r/
R)$$ is correct.

Comment: Since -Kq/(r+R)-{-Kq/(r-R)} =
POSITIVE.  We have positive potential difference and not potential. Eg: let potential at two points is -3V and - 5V. PD would be+2 V while potential is still negative.

Comment: ok sir change it.

Comment: First, I think we are both in same class 12 .So, no, sir. Second, your question about, why there is potential difference, solved?So, answer is appropriate.
Third, your next question is how much potential is at center of sphere. Answer, -kq/r. Forth, you want mathematical solution to question without considering symmetry. Ask it as new question, since I don't have much knowledge about Richard's physics.

Comment: sir i had a few facts unclear about your answer .If u pls clarify then it would be totally understood. ##### no 1.SIR,  how do you get this following equation correct ? -Kq/(r - R) + Kq'/(r/R) = -Kq/(r+R) - Kq'/(r/R).

Comment: sir image is not unclear. what is unclear is the equation that u claimed to be correct.  -Kq/(r - R) + Kq'/(r/R) = -Kq/(r+R) - Kq'/(r/R).  and u can have a look in ur edits.

Comment: SIR i know i am bothering u but pls keep patience to help me. SIR tell me where i have my first inducing charge (written in the question) is it in right or left side from the sphere?

Comment: Right hand side.

Comment: Electric field lines begin from +ve charge and end towards -ve.

Comment: Your answer is about to understand but one thing u wrote that we assumed +q' which induced +ve charge. But how positive can induce positive charge.?

Comment: No, positive charge was induced at N due to outer negative charge. The net +ve charge induced is what I represented by **q'**.

Comment: Sir pls clarify me this sentence """" As +ve charge is induced at N , consider a charge +q'at distance r/R from N which had induced this +ve charge.""""

Comment: Do you live in India sir? Then, can you give me your phone number?

Comment: There is nothing much unclear in this sentence sir. See sir there is positive charge induced at area near N. OK? You very well know about centre of mass and effective mass concept. Similarly sir, you can consider a point at distance $\frac{r}{R}$ from center of sphere. There you can consider an effective charge q' which is causing that +ve field there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41489/discussion-between-ffahim-and-anubhav-goel).

Answer (score 0):

First there will be a potential on the conductor and the potential on earth is zero. when we ground it there will be a potential difference, so the electrons will move until the potential difference becomes zero. Then finally the potential on the conductor will also be zero.

Comment: ok then what would be the voltage of that conductor.is it positive or negative?

Comment: As we bought a negative charge near to the conductor there will be a negative voltage on conductor. when we ground it the electron will move from low voltage(conductor) to high voltage(earth).

Comment: but why there is negative voltage cause the conductor is still neutral(before grounding) why there is voltage difference pls clear me.

Comment: when you bring a negative charge the negative charge will create an electric field. therefore there will be a voltage in every point all over the field. so even though the conductor is neutral there will be a voltage because of the negative charge which is near to it.

Comment: ok I understood the above fact but how we'll calculate that there is a negative potential in that conductor.

Comment: voltage on every point of conductor will vary because of the different distance. every electron will feel a different voltage difference and will move according to that.