# electric potential and other potentials

Tags: electricity, potential, potential-energy

We know that without potential difference no electric current can flow.If two conductors carrying positive and negative charge respectively then the first one will have positive and the rest one will have negative potential.Now if I join these conductors with a conducting path then after some time both of the conductors will have neutral charge and zero potentials. So here are my questions ##why any object having + or - potential want to be zero potential?

why no electric current flows between two neutrally charged conductors?

Answer (score 0):

Current do flow in neutral objects, it's just that net current is zero.

Now, consider that A is +ve and B is -ve.
Then when you connect them, free electrons of B are attracted by +ve charged A, which you said as both like 0 potential. While truth is that there is no tendency towards 0 potential but there is just electrostatic attractions giving current.

Comment: Hello sir as u r here then pls give an final answer   http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/230440/94536     including richard feynman's physics ..... for the last time. pls write it from the beginning .